# Showing that $(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \leq 8$, where $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $D^2$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in D^2$.
I can't show that 
$$(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 \leq 8.$$
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Try using the facts that $x_1^2 + y_1^2 \leq 1$ and $x_2^2 + y_2^2 \leq 1$ along with some bound on $|x_1|$, $|x_2|$, $|y_1|$, $|y_2|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more circuitous, but more general, argument using the triangle inequality several times and the fact that if a point lies inside the unit disk, all of its coordinates must have magnitude no greater than $1$:
\begin{align*}
(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 &=\big| (x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2\big| \\
&= \big|x_2^2 - 2x_1x_2 + x_1^2 + y_2^2 - 2y_1y_2 + y_1^2\big| \\
&= \big|(x_1^2 + y_1^2) + (x_2^2 + y_2^2) - 2(x_1x_2 + y_1y_2)\big| \\
&\leq \big|x_1^2\big| + \big|y_1^2\big| + \big|x_2^2\big| + \big|y_2^2\big| + 2\bigg(\big|x_1x_2\big| + \big|y_1y_2\big|\bigg)\\
&\leq 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2(|x_1||x_2|+|y_1||y_2|)\\
&\leq 4 + 2(1 + 1)\\
&= 8
\end{align*}

(Note that *this* argument actually holds for any point in the unit *square*, not just the unit disk.)

Comment: Why all the coordinates have magnitude no greater than 1?

Comment: @g.pomegranate if $(x,y)\in D^2$ then $1\geq \|(x,y)\|^2 = x^2 + y^2 \geq x^2$ hence $|x| \leq 1$ and $|y|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 5):

The inequality can actually be tighter... The geometric argument is straightforward:
$$
(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2
$$
is the squared distance between the two points. As these lay inside the unit disk, their distance is as most 2, therefore
$$
(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2\leq 4.
$$

Answer (score 2):

If we apply the euclidean norm, as we have that the maximum distance between the pair of coordinates $x_1,x_2$ and $y_1,y_2$ is 2, meaning that they are at the opposite extremes of the disc, we can then show:

$$ \lVert (x_1 - x_2)^2\rVert + \lVert (y_1 - y_2)^2 \rVert \leq 2^2 + 2^2 = 8$$

Comment: This is also true if you use the *unit square* ($|x|\leq1$, $|y|\leq1$).

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2=x_1^2+y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2-2(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)\leq$$
$$\leq2+2\sqrt{(x_1^2+y_1^2)(x_2^2+y_2^2)}\leq4<8$$